How to let KP_Down, KP_Up, KP_Next, KP_Prior scroll a `ttk.Treeview` widget like KeyPress-Down, KeyPress-Up, KeyPress-Next, KeyPress-Prior?
I discovered that in tkinter, '<KP_Down>','<KP_Up>', '<KP_Next>', '<KP_Prior>' does not scroll a ttk.Treeview widget as '<KeyPress-Down>', '<KeyPress-Up>', '<KeyPress-Next>', '<KeyPress-Prior>' respectively would by default? The sample code below shows these behaviours.
How do I let '<KP_Down>' scroll the Treeview like how '<KeyPress-Down>' does? The same question applies to '<KP_Up>', '<KP_Next>', '<KP_Prior>' respective to '<KeyPress-Up>', '<KeyPress-Next>', '<KeyPress-Prior>'.
import random
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.master = master
        self.tree = None
        self.ysb = None
        self.xsb = None
        self.create_widgets()
        self.create_bindings()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(
            self.master, height=10, selectmode='extended', takefocus=True,
            columns=("x", "y", "z"), displaycolumns=["x", "y", "z"])
        self.tree.heading('#0', text="Points")
        self.tree.heading('x', text='X', anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading('y', text='Y', anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading('z', text='Z', anchor='center')
        self.tree.column('#0', stretch=True, width=100)
        self.tree.column('x', stretch=True, anchor='center', width=50)
        self.tree.column('y', stretch=True, anchor='center', width=50)
        self.tree.column('z', stretch=True, anchor='center', width=50)

        self.ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(
            self.master, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
        self.xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(
            self.master, orient='horizontal', command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree.configure(
            yscrollcommand=self.ysb.set, xscrollcommand=self.xsb.set)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')

        groups = ["Local", "Remote"]
        for n, group in enumerate(groups):
            self.tree.insert(
                "", 'end', iid=f'G{n}', text=group, open=True)
            for i in range(10):
                self.tree.insert(
                    f'G{n}', 'end', iid=f'G{n}-D{i}',
                    text=f'G{n}-D{i}',
                    values=[
                        random.randrange(0, 20),
                        random.randrange(0, 20),
                        random.randrange(0, 20)
                    ]
                )

    def create_bindings(self):
        self.tree.bind('<KeyPress-Down>', self.kp_down)
        self.tree.bind('<KeyPress-Up>', self.kp_up)
        self.tree.bind('<KeyPress-Next>', self.kp_down)
        self.tree.bind('<KeyPress-Prior>', self.kp_up)
        self.tree.bind('<KP_Down>', self.kp_down)
        self.tree.bind('<KP_Up>', self.kp_up)
        self.tree.bind('<KP_Next>', self.kp_down)
        self.tree.bind('<KP_Prior>', self.kp_up)

    def kp_down(self, event):
        print(f"{event.keysym}")

    def kp_up(self, event):
        print(f"{event.keysym}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    root.mainloop()


Try using self.tree.event_generate("<KeyPress-Next>") but I am not 100% sure if that will work as <KeyPress-Next> isn't a virtual event (you will also need to remove the binding for <KeyPress-Next>)

@TheLizzard Thanks. ;) I was just typing out my answer when you replied. I came to the same conclusion as you too of using event_generate.

I'd consider it not working by default to be an outright (if minor) bug.

@DonalFellows Is this a TCL/TK or tkinter issue? If the former, any plans to fix this bug in v8.7?

It sounds like a base Tk issue (though I've not yet looked) and as a bug would be a candidate for fixing in 8.6. Setting the class bindings is a reasonable workaround; the fix will probably do something very similar.

What platform is this a problem on? What state is the keyboard in (numlock state especially). Where do we need to improve our support and testing regime?

@DonalFellows I experienced the issue in Linux 6.5.0-44-generic #44~22.04.1-Ubuntu x86_64. Numlock was not switched on. I am grateful to be able to get good help from the TCL/TK and tkinter community in Stackoverflow. Hope this avenue will not disappear, but if it does disappear I hope another help avenue will be available.

I think you can also try using the following alternative method:
def create_bindings(self):
    # the beginning of change
    event_down = self.tree.bind_class('Treeview', '<KeyPress-Down>')
    event_up = self.tree.bind_class('Treeview', '<KeyPress-Up>')
    event_next = self.tree.bind_class('Treeview', '<KeyPress-Next>')
    event_prior = self.tree.bind_class('Treeview', '<KeyPress-Prior>')
    self.tree.bind_class('Treeview', '<KP_Down>', event_down)
    self.tree.bind_class('Treeview', '<KP_Up>', event_up)
    self.tree.bind_class('Treeview', '<KP_Next>', event_next)
    self.tree.bind_class('Treeview', '<KP_Prior>', event_prior)
    # end of changes

    self.tree.bind('<KeyPress-Down>', self.kp_down)
    self.tree.bind('<KeyPress-Up>', self.kp_up)
    self.tree.bind('<KeyPress-Next>', self.kp_down)
    self.tree.bind('<KeyPress-Prior>', self.kp_up)
    self.tree.bind('<KP_Down>', self.kp_down)
    self.tree.bind('<KP_Up>', self.kp_up)
    self.tree.bind('<KP_Next>', self.kp_down)
    self.tree.bind('<KP_Prior>', self.kp_up)

I don't know if this method is better or worse. But this solution will make the "<KP_Down>", "<KP_Up>", "<KP_Next>" and "<KP_Prior>" bindings work for all your treeviews by default.

A good practice in answering a question is to first test out your solution before answering.

@SunBear I wish I could test, but I am on Windows and so the "KP" bindings don't work. But it works if I set the binding to some other keys. Am I right that this solution doesn't work for you?

I am not aware KP don't work for Windows. You might want to raise a separate question on why this is the case to investigate.  FYI, w.bind_class(className, sequence=None, func=None, add=None).

Your answer works on Linux.

I made the following changes to this method:
def create_bindings(self):
    self.tree.bind('<KeyPress-Down>', self.kp_down)
    self.tree.bind('<KeyPress-Up>', self.kp_up)
    self.tree.bind('<KeyPress-Next>', self.kp_down)
    self.tree.bind('<KeyPress-Prior>', self.kp_up)
    self.tree.bind('<KP_Down>', self.activate_keypad_scrolling)   #changed
    self.tree.bind('<KP_Up>', self.activate_keypad_scrolling)     #changed
    self.tree.bind('<KP_Next>', self.activate_keypad_scrolling)   #changed
    self.tree.bind('<KP_Prior>', self.activate_keypad_scrolling)  #changed

Also, I added this method to the class to generate the events:
def activate_keypad_scrolling(self, event):
    match event.keysym:
        case 'KP_Down':
            self.tree.event_generate('<KeyPress-Down>')
        case 'KP_Up':
            self.tree.event_generate('<KeyPress-Up>')
        case 'KP_Next':
            self.tree.event_generate('<KeyPress-Next>')
        case 'KP_Prior':
            self.tree.event_generate('<KeyPress-Prior>')

